# Nginx выдает 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: nginx, fileupload

Когда пытаюсь загрузить файл больше, чем разрешено nginx, то выбивает ошибка 413 Request Entity Too Large. Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы при этой ошибке скрипт не прерывался, а продолжал отрабатывать?

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт загрузки на сайте должен продолжить работу?
Необходимо изменить скрипт так, что бы он в случае получения от nginx данной ошибки выводил предупреждение "размер файла больше разрешенного для загрузки" и возвращался к началу процесса загрузки (обеспечить цикл).
как-то так

Comment: Ну это я понял, вот в этом и вопрос, как это сделать =)

Comment: тут, к сож, помочь не смогу... сам не скриптописатель.